# jQuery .click() didn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is the story:
After I finished my picture carousel and navigation bar, I decided to put a click event on the "home" (to remove the picture carousel and display other items). But the `click()` didn't work .

To be more precise, I'm sure that the `click()` has been working (after I clicked "Home", it disappeared for an instant).

I had tried to replace `remove()` with `css("display","none")` or `empty()`, but the results were the same.

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>untitle</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="generator" content="Bluefish 2.2.7" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="slider.css" />
</head>
<body>
        <div id="head">
         <ul>
            <li id="home"><a href="" class="a1">Home</a></li>
            <li class="topnav a1">
                <a href="" class="a1">Fortunate</a>
                <ul class="subnav">
                    <li><a href="#" class="menu">A</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="menu">B</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="menu">C</a></li>
                </ul> 
            </li>
            <li><a href="" class="a1">Breed</a></li>
            <li><a href="" class="a1">Market</a></li>
            <li><a href="" class="a1">Box</a></li>
            <li><a href="" class="a1">Message</a></li>
        </ul> 
        </div>

        <div id="container">
        <ul id="picList">
                <li><img src="1.jpg" alt="" class="a"></li>
                <li><img src="2.jpg" alt="" class="a"></li> 
                <li><img src="3.jpg" alt="" class="a"></li> 
                <li><img src="4.jpg" alt="" class="a"></li>     
            <img src="prev.png" alt="" class="prev">
            <img src="next.png" alt="" class="next">
        </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JQuery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myFunc.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var maxWidth=document.body.clientWidth;
    (function () {                                 //picture carousel
        $("#container,img.a").css("width",maxWidth)
        var intervalObj=window.setInterval(next,3000);
        var picArr=$("#picList li");
        $("#picList").css("width",picArr.length*maxWidth);

        function next(){
            $("#picList li:first-child").animate({
                marginLeft:-maxWidth
            },1000,function(){
                var temp=$(this).clone();
                $(this).remove();
                temp.css({marginLeft:"0"});
                $("#picList").append(temp);
            });
        }
        function prev(){
            var temp=$("#picList li:last-child").clone();
            $("#picList li:last-child").remove();
            temp.css({marginLeft:-maxWidth});
            $("#picList").prepend(temp);
            $("#picList li:first-child").animate({
                marginLeft:"0"
            },1000);
        }
        $("img.prev").bind("click",function(){ prev();}).hide();
        $("img.next").bind("click",function(){ next();}).hide();

        $("#container").mouseover(function(){
          $("img.prev,img.next").show();
            window.clearInterval(intervalObj);

        });
        $("#container").mouseout(function(){
            $("img.prev,img.next").hide();
            intervalObj=window.setInterval(next,2000);

        }); 
    })();

    (function(){    $("ul.subnav").hide();
        $(".topnav").hover(function(){
            $(".subnav").slideDown();}             //menu slideDown
        ,function(){$(".subnav").slideUp();});

    })();

        $("#home").click(function(){
        // $("#container").css("height","100px");  
        // this is my test,it works but just for an instant
        $("#container").remove();
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to paste your code and the first thing I notice is that you want to prevent the default action of the anchor link. That way it doesn't "flash" the screen.

So what exactly are you trying to do? Just remove the #container element?

```
$("#home").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // $("#container").css("height","100px");  
    // this is my test,it works but just for an instant
    $("#container").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Clicking the link will reload the page. So you have to prevent this first to  see the desired result

```
 $("#home a").on("click",function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $("#container").hide(); //or remove
        //other codes if necessary
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a little carried away (read was bored) and did a total rewrite on your carrousel setup to make it a bit more readable and optimized it, o and I fixed the remove of course.

Have a look: https://jsfiddle.net/849wg8wv/

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function Carrousel(container, maxWidth, pictures) {
    var self = this,
        ul = $('<ul></ul>'),
        interval = 3000,
        intervalObj,
        animationDuration = 1000,
        listItems = [],
        prevBtn = $('<button class="prev">previous</button>'),
        nextBtn = $('<button class="next">next</button>');

    prevBtn.hide();
    nextBtn.hide();

    container.append(ul);

    pictures.forEach(function(src) {
        var li = $('<li></li>'),
            img = $('<img src="'+src+'"></img>');

        img.css('width', maxWidth);

        li.append(img);
        ul.append(li);

        listItems.push(li);
    });

    ul.css('width', listItems.length * maxWidth);
    ul.append(prevBtn);
    ul.append(nextBtn);

    this.next = function () {
        var firstSlide = listItems[0],
            lastSlide = listItems[listItems.length-1];

        firstSlide.animate(
            { marginLeft: -maxWidth },
            animationDuration,
            function () {
                firstSlide.detach().insertAfter(lastSlide);
                firstSlide.css({ marginLeft: 0} );

                listItems.shift();
                listItems.push(firstSlide);
            }
        );
    }

    this.prev = function(){
        var firstSlide = listItems[0],
            lastSlide = listItems[listItems.length-1];

        lastSlide.animate(
            { marginLeft: -maxWidth },
            animationDuration,
            function () {
                lastSlide.detach().insertBefore(firstSlide);
                lastSlide.css({ marginLeft: 0 })

                listItems.pop();
                listItems.unshift(lastSlide);
            }
        );
    }

    this.remove = function () {
        clearInterval(intervalObj);
        container.remove();
    }

    this.start = function () {
        intervalObj = setInterval(self.next, interval);
    }

    this.stop = function () {
        clearInterval(intervalObj);
    }

    prevBtn.bind('click', self.prev);
    nextBtn.bind('click', self.next);

    container.mouseover(function() {
        prevBtn.show();
        nextBtn.show();
        self.stop();
    });

    container.mouseout(function () {
        prevBtn.hide();
        nextBtn.hide();
        self.start();
    });

    this.start();
};

var carousel = new Carrousel(
    $('#container'),
    300,
    [
        'http://www.relatably.com/m/img/funniest-cat-memes/cat-memes-10.png',
        'http://www.relatably.com/m/img/funniest-cat-memes/Top-30-Funny-Cat-Memes-Hilarious.jpg',
        'http://www.relatably.com/m/img/funniest-cat-memes/Funny-Cat-Pictures-with-Captions-25.jpg',
        'http://www.relatably.com/m/img/funniest-cat-memes/Funny-Cat-Meme-Work-1.jpg'
    ]
);

$("#home").on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  carousel.remove();
});
});
```

Comment: `carousel.listItems[3]` is hilarious.